# Kendo UI Web MultiSelect - How should I build the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-ui

I need to link a single page to multiple categories and store the relationship(s) in a database. I want to make this possible by using the MultiSelect widget bundled with Kendo UI Web. CategoryId is the foreign key from the Category table.

In theory, Categories should work in a similar manner to the Tag system here on SO. Is there a recommended method or sample out there to show me how this can be done?

Here's a sample of my Page model:

```
public int PageId { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }

public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

I've tried using the following but to no avail:

```
public List<int> CategoryId { get; set; }
```

Please note that I'm not using the MVC Server Wrappers and instead using JavaScript for the views. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your list items from int to string:

```
public List<string> CategoryId { get; set; }
```

See this answer for more details:
[Kendo Multiselect: Selected values from binded model are not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544982/kendo-multiselect-selected-values-from-binded-model-are-not-initialized)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've given it a shot, same problem as using List<int>. The loading icon appears and the categories don't show up. Let me have a closer look at the question you posted. Maybe I should take the ViewModel approach.